# How we merge two database into new database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two databases in my phpmyadmin 
 `test and test1` now I want to merge it into other  database  i.e `test3`

Database `test` has 15 tables . Database `test 2` has 23 tables  so that database `test 3` contain 15+23 i.e 38  table

I also  check [Merge two database into a single database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171956/merge-two-database-into-a-single-database) and  [How can we merge two databases with identical schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657242/how-can-we-merge-two-databases-with-identical-schemas) link but not found any solution

How it can be done with the help of php??

Comment: are the table names different between the two existing databases?

Comment: yes all are different !! table name having prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using php file first of all you need to take dump of multiple database using `exec()` and `mysqldump` as

```
exec("mysqldump --user root -p --databases test1 test2 > file.sql");
```

This will export multiple database into one file now you can import database into test3 using

```
exec("mysql -u username -p test3 < file.sql");
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT THIS IS WORKING!!

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned phpmyadmin you can do this all in phpmyadmin.

First export both databases (test1 and test2) as SQL. You can follow instructions in this [post](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403864/export-and-import-mysql-databases). Then you can import both of these databases in into test3 using phpmyadmin also.

You probably want to make sure that there are no conflicts with table names to avoid test1 overwriting test2 tables (or vice versa). If you want to keep these tables separate then you can add a prefix to all tables but it really depends what you're trying to do. Since you're expecting 38 tables I am assuming that you don't want to mix the data.

Comment: that's a solution using GUI. I need to do using php script!!

Comment: you can use the command in php script  with exec command and you can use the following command to copy one db into another.  mysqldump -u user1 -ppassword1 databasename > dump.sql
mysql -u user2 -ppassword2 databasename < dump.sql

Comment: Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of the table names are different and we are talking tables only (Im unsure on triggers and other operations) you could use the "Copy database to:
" feature in PHPmyAdmin to do this follow these steps;

1. Select the database `test1`
2. Go to the operations navigation item along the top
3. Go to the `Copy database to:` section and then enter `test3` as the database you wish to migrate to. 
   [image: Copy Database To]
4. Repeat for `test2`

Comment: that's a solution using GUI. I need to do using php script!!

Comment: Why? It makes no sense to write a PHP script when there are so many tables involved? What are the tables called ? Are they `table1`, `table2` ?

Comment: Thanks for your support